# Error while uploading my streamlit app on Heroku platform. What should I do to solve this issue?

Tags: python, heroku, streamlit

Error Message:

ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 0.10.6 Requires-Python >=2.7, <3.6; 0.10.7 Requires-Python >=2.7, <3.6; 0.55.2 Requires-Python <3.5
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=223 (from pypiwin32) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pywin32>=223
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
!     Push failed

Comment: pywin is a windows dependency. You are deploying your project to Heroku which runs on Linux. Why do you need the windows dependency? If your project requires it then it's not possible to run on Linux.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I just deleted that entry from my requirements.txt and app was deployed on Heroku.